# weird problem with UILabel

Tags: ios, uilabel

I am using UILabel for custom cells in my `UITableView`. Heres all the code that I am using :

header file:

```
UILabel *timeLabels;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *timeLabels;
```

code file:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier

    timeLabels=[[UILabel alloc] init];
    timeLabels.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
    timeLabels.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
    timeLabels.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    timeLabels.textColor=[UIColor blueColor];

- (void) layoutSubviews

   frame=CGRectMake(boundsX+5, 5, 60, 45);
   timeLabels.frame=frame;
```

---

```
[timeLabels release]
```

I am getting the following error on    `timeLabels.frame=frame`;

```
2011-08-08 12:44:07.290 EncameoApp[2014:707] -[NSCFString setFrame:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x136890
2011-08-08 12:44:07.361 EncameoApp[2014:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString setFrame:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x136890'
```

Which is pretty strange given that timeLabels is not a NSString, but rather a UILabel !

Can anyone please let me know what I missed here ? Thanks.

Comment: Somewhere in your code (not in your example) you are accidentally setting timeLabels to a string. Instead of saying `timeLabels.text = @"blah";` your doing `timeLabels = @"blah"` (it happens). Check your compiler warnings as well may help you find it quicker

Comment: Is that _all_ the code that is in the `-layoutSubviews`?  Also, I'd steer clear of addressing the ivars explicitly--the getters/setters generated by `@synthesize` serve an important memory management role.  Accessing the ivars directly (without `self.`) preempts this.

Comment: @Brennon : there are more UILabels and UIImageViews there -- those work nicely ! how do I use the getters/setters generated by @ synthesize ? I am a newbee, and dont know that much.

Comment: @Joe : thanks a bunch...i had done it in some other place !...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also faced this kind of problem, but i had solved this problem by set value of timeLabels as following:-

```
timeLabels.text = @"value";
```

instead of

```
timeLabels = @"value";
```

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet you show is correct, anyway my guess is that you have very possibly a memory problem that makes your `UILabel` instance to be released at some point before `layoutSubviews` is executed, then that memory is reused by an `NSString`, so you get the error there.

In my experience, the most common case for this to happen is anyway erroneously overwriting `timeLabels` with the wrong value could produce the same result. This could be done within the class or from another class (that maybe tries to set the label value).

If you want to make a simple test, add

```
 NSLog(@"timeLabels address %x", timeLabels);
```

both to `init` and to `layoutSubviews` to compare the two values and see that they differ (or maybe they don't, in this case you would have a memory corruption problem).

You should inspect your code, and post more of it if you need more help.